# Convert PySpark data frame to dictionary after grouping the elements in the column as key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have below PySpark data frame:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value-1 |
| 1 | value-2 |
| 1 | value-3 |
| 2 | value-1 |
| 2 | value-2 |

I want to convert it into a dictionary:

```py
dict1 = {'1':['value-1','value-2','value-3'], '2':['value-1','value-2']}
```

I was able to do it (wrote an answer below) but I need much simpler and efficient way without converting the data frame to Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple and efficient approach using [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) which will produce the same desired output.

```py
# Convert to Pandas data frame
df_pandas = df_spark.toPandas()

dict1 = df_pandas.groupby("ID")["Value"].apply(list).to_dict()
print(dict1)
```

You can do the following if you want to avoid `.toPandas()`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

dict1 = df_spark.groupBy("ID").agg(collect_list("Value").alias("Values")).rdd.collectAsMap()
print(dict1)
```

---

```
{'1': ['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3'], '2': ['value-1', 'value-2']}
```

Comment: Even though I like this answer, I don't really want to convert the dataframe to Pandas because it is a costly operation on clusters. Hence upvoted it. Thanks.

Comment: I added an alternative to the answer which you can refer to see if that helps.

Comment: Actually I am trying to convert 2 different dataframes to dictionaries in the same way in the same notebook. Few months back it worked for both dataframes, but now, it is working only for the first dataframe while 2nd conversion fails with AnalysisException saying "Value" column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can try:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

records = df.groupBy('ID').agg(F.collect_list('Value').alias('List')).collect()
dict1 = {row['ID']: row['List'] for row in records}
print(dict1)

# Output
{1: ['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3'], 2: ['value-1', 'value-2']}
```

Comment: This answer is also useful in generating the desired output. I have a question related to ```collect()```.  Isn't it costly ? Just like converting dataframe to Pandas, wouldn't ```collect()``` also gather all data into single node in the entire cluster?

Comment: Yes but you have no choice... The difference here is your dataframe is already aggregated so you have to collect less records. Obviously, use `select` before to get only two desired columns! Another way is to create an UDF function?

Answer (score 0):

I first converted the PySpark data frame to pandas data frame then iterate through all cells. This is O(M*N) to iterate but the costly part is to convert PySpark data frame to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

# Convert to Pandas data frame
df_pandas = df_spark.toPandas()

# Convert pandas data frame to dictionary
dict1= dict()
for i in range(0,len(df_pandas)):
    key = df_pandas.iloc[i, 0]
    if key not in dict1:
        dict1.update({key:[]})
        dict1[key].append(df_pandas.iloc[i, 1])
    else:
        dict1[key].append(df_pandas.iloc[i, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

aggregation = df.groupby("ID").agg(F.collect_list("Value").alias("Value"))
dict(aggregation.rdd.map(lambda x: (x["ID"], x["Value"])).collect())
```